# How can I tell when a power is ready to use?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-3

I'm playing the PS3 version of Mass Effect 3 and for the life of me I can't find out whether my Tactical Cloak is ready or not without opening the Skill menu (hold R2) or just using the Cloak and seeing if it works.

Is there a way to tell when my hotkey ability cooldowns have ended without opening a menu or using them?

Comment: Does the PS3 not show a hotbar at the top left of the screen? Because that sucks if so. :(

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz doesn't look like it, there's just the health/weapon area of the HUD. I can see when my squad's powers are ready to activate but not *mine*, unless I'm missing something. Don't see any options for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little red circle that appears when you use an active power that has a cooldown.  It starts out as two halves, and as the power recharges, the circle starts to close around your crosshairs.  When the circle halves meet in the center of the screen, it flashes white and disappears.  At this point, the power's ready to use again.

Comment: 12 seconds. >:/

Comment: @BenBrocka cooldowns are increased with the more weight being carried (mostly through weapons).  If you unequip some weapons you don't find yourself using, you can drastically decrease cooldowns

Comment: @DaveMcClelland didn't know that, thanks

Comment: Also, there's probably a way to reduce cooldowns as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out two halves of a red circle appear when your cooldown starts and slowly slide toward the center of the screen. Once those hemicircles join and start to fade away your cooldown is over and the skill can be used again.

The circle is focused on your crosshair, so it's hard to miss when the circle "joins"...I just didn't know what the circles were about.